# Internal System.Linq.Set<T> vs public System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<T>

Tags: c#, linq, hashset

Check out this piece of code from `Linq.Enumerable` class:

```
static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctIterator<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, IEqualityComparer<TSource> comparer) {
        Set<TSource> set = new Set<TSource>(comparer);
        foreach (TSource element in source)
            if (set.Add(element)) yield return element; 
    }
```

Why did the guys at Microsoft decided to use this internal implementation of `Set` and not the regular `HashSet`? If it's better in any way, why not exposing it to the public?

Answer (score 12):

The implementation of this `Set<T>` is far simpler than `HashSet<T>` as it is only needs to add and remove elements and check for existence for LINQ internal processes. It does not implement any interfaces or expose iterators etc.

So probably it is faster for the purpose LINQ uses it for.